# Swimlanes background colour change

Tags: microsoft-visio-2016

When I export my visio file to a webpage the background of the swimlanes changes from white to blue. I recently added more swimlanes and after exporting it as a webpage the new lanes are a lighter shade of blue. Is there a setting that I can change so that this doesn't happen?

Thanks.

Comment: I've just tried it and it seems to work fine. How are you setting the background colour? CFF styles or themes or what? Which web browser do you view the webpage output in? Do you use Silverlight?